# Setting transparent background to UINavigationBar cause to bad transition effect when using static UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationbar

I'm facing this weird situation where I want to have a transparent `UINavigationBar` but for some reason the transitioning from one screen to another is not smooth. In the other screen, I have this static `UITableView` which I've configured with the `storyboard`. While transitioning, it keeps showing the previous screen until the next screen is finally there.
In order to reproduce this issue I've wrote the following demo app with Xcode 5:
File-->New Project.

This is my storyboard:
[image]

This is the code I wrote in `viewDidLoad` method of `MyTableViewController`:

```objective-c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *bgName = @"bg.jpg";

        // those lines are for making transparent navigation bar
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                        forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];

        // those lines for the background of the table view and its container
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bgName]];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

I'm starting with my root view controller:

[image]

After pressing the button (configured in storyboard to push `MyTableViewController` and this are the issue I'm facing:

[image]

Finally I have my desired screen, static table with transparent `UINavigationBar`:

[image]

Please comment if any further, relevant, data is missing for you to help me with it.

Any help is kindly appreciated,

Cheers!

**Edit - @Greg Answer**
I've also tried the following, it prevents the transition issue but then my `UINavigationBar` is translucent and not 100% clear

```objective-c
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mystatic"])
{
    MyTableViewController *viewController = (MyTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSString *bgName = @"bg.jpg";

    [viewController.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil;

     // I have also tried this
//      [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil
//                                                    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
//      self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil;

     viewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bgName]];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you call `[UIImage new]`? You should call nil instead. Can you move this code from viewDidLoad method to your RootVC and in prepareForSegue: set it for your destinationController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOURIDENTIFIER"])
    {
        MyTableViewController *viewController = (MyTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        [viewController.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:...
        //If it doesn't work try
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:... 
        // But when you pop to root view controller you have to change navigation bar back to match you root view controller design
        //rest of your code here
    }
}
```

Try that and let me know is it work for you.

Comment: I get `segue.identifier = null` at the if condition. Recall, the button configured via the storyboard, not by coding

Comment: There is a segue between root view controller and my table in storyboard. Click on it and set up a name, you can google if you not sure.

Comment: oh... sorry, I accidentally put the ID to the wrong component. Anyway, it didn't work. Please see my edit with your answer - maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me the same problem, the background of the UIView (which was a UIImageView) was frizzy during the transition. The way I could solve was using:

```
self.view.clipToBounds = true
```

or in the IB (Identity Inspector), check on clip subviews, on the view of the ViewController.

In my case, the image was very large, had to occupy the entire screen (top, bottom, left, right), apparently when the transition was overflowed and tried to take it.